# React Native Stripe Direct payment from customer to driver

Tags: android, react-native, stripe-payments, payment, payout

I am building a react native texi booking application where the app has two roles one is user and other driver. User book a ride and user pay the charges to driver. The payment gateway I am using is stripe which is integrated already and I am able to charge customer which certain amount but the payment goes to business owner stripe account instead of driver. I would like to know what should be mechanism through which I can directly pay to driver from customer card.Any help would be wonderful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pay the driver directly from the customer's card, you can make use of [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect). With Stripe Connect, you can easily manage payments and payouts to third-party accounts such as drivers.

To implement this, you can use the "[Separate Charge and Transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers)" feature of Stripe. When a customer books a ride, you can charge their card and hold the funds in your Stripe account. Then, you can create a separate transfer to the driver's account, which will transfer the funds directly to their Stripe account.

You can also use Stripe Connect to manage the driver's account and handle [payouts automatically](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/bank-debit-card-payouts). Stripe Connect allows you to easily manage payouts, track balances, and handle disputes.

In order to use Stripe Connect, you will need to create a Stripe account for your application and enable Connect. You will also need to obtain the necessary permissions and authorizations to access the driver's account.

You can do several test using your Stripe Test mode and these [Connect Test data](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing).

Comment: Thanks @os4m37 I want to know these are two different methods ? Like Separate charge and transfer and via connect?

Comment: Nope they are attached, Separate Charge and transfer are on of the charges type that Stripe Connect provides:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges